# How do I cast a raw pointer to a pytorch tensor of a specific shape?

Tags: python, pytorch

I get a raw pointer from a C++ library which I would like to interpret (in a "`reinterpret_cast`-like fashion) as a pytorch tensor of a specific shape. Since the code is executed in a performance critical section, I really want to make sure that no heap allocations and/or copy operations are performed.

Here is what I got right now:

```
def as_tensor(pointer, shape):
    return torch.from_numpy(numpy.array(numpy.ctypeslib.as_array(pointer, shape = shape)))

shape = (2, 3, 4)
x = torch.zeros(shape)

p = ctypes.cast(x.data_ptr(), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))
y = as_tensor(p, shape)
```

Is it really necessary to cast to a numpy array before? And I'm also not 100% sure if the call to `numpy.array(...)` doesn't copy the content of what the `as_array()` call is pointing to.

Comment: is it not redundant to have `torch.from_numpy(numpy.array())` to get a `tensor` from a `numpy` `array` when `torch.tensor()` can take a `numpy` `array` as input?

Comment: `numpy.array` definitely makes a copy.  It creates a new numpy array object.  You need to remember that these objects need direct control over the memory and its interpretation.  It's possible that torch doesn't have to make a new copy, and can just wrap the numpy object.

Comment: @OriYardenPhD Yes, it is redundant, but it seems like there is no analogue to `numpy.ctypeslib.as_array()` for torch tensors.

Comment: @TimRoberts But how do I cast a pointer to a torch tensor directly?

Comment: I just want you to get your mental model correct.  A torch tensor is not just a pointer.  A torch tensor is a full-fledged Python object that has a great deal of state information, part of which is a wrapper to a non-Python memory stream that contains numeric data.

Comment: @TimRoberts That's actually the way I already looked at this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a one-dimensional ctypes array object from pointer and shape. It implements the buffer protocol, so it can be converted to a one-dimensional tensor which is finally reshaped.

The code at the end shows that `x` and `y` share the same memory.

```
import torch
import ctypes
from math import prod

# It additionally needs the ctypes type as torch type
def as_tensor(pointer, shape, torch_type):
    arr = (pointer._type_ * prod(shape)).from_address(
        ctypes.addressof(pointer.contents))
    
    return torch.frombuffer(arr, dtype=torch_type).view(*shape)

shape = (2, 3, 4)
x = torch.zeros(shape)

p = ctypes.cast(x.data_ptr(), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))

y = as_tensor(p, shape, torch.float)

print(y)  # Print created tensor

x[1,1,0] = 3.  # Modify original

print(y)  # Print again
```

Output:

```
tensor([[[0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0.]]])
tensor([[[0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [3., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0.]]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You have a small typo: It should be `pointer` instead of `p` in your definition of `as_tensor`. Apart from that, your solution worked pretty well for me.

Comment: However, now I noticed something weird: I have an image `x` of shape `(3, 512, 512)` (the first dimension being the color channel count). When I save it as an `*.exr`-file, using `imageio.imsave`, the output is the correct image. Now, when I write `y = as_tensor(ctypes.cast(x.data_ptr(), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)), x.shape, torch.float)` and save this an `*.exr`, I get the previous image repeated in a 3x3 grid. What is going on here? What I would expected is clearly `x = y` (in terms of the data).

Comment: I've asked a separate question for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78228326/547231.

Answer (score 0):

To interpret a raw pointer from a C++ library as a PyTorch tensor of a specific shape without performing heap allocations or copy operations, you can directly create a PyTorch tensor by specifying the data pointer and shape. Here's a modified version of your code that aims to avoid unnecessary copies:

```
import torch
import ctypes

def as_tensor(pointer, shape):
    # Create a PyTorch tensor from a raw pointer without copying data
    tensor = torch.as_tensor(pointer, dtype=torch.float32)
    # Reshape the tensor to the specified shape
    return tensor.view(shape)

shape = (2, 3, 4)
x = torch.zeros(shape)

p = ctypes.cast(x.data_ptr(), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))
y = as_tensor(p, shape)
```

In this revised version:

We use `torch.as_tensor()` to create a PyTorch tensor directly from the raw pointer without involving any copy operations.
By using `torch.as_tensor()` instead of torch.from_numpy() , we avoid the intermediate step of converting to a NumPy array, which can potentially involve unnecessary copying.
The `view()` method is used to reshape the tensor to the specified shape without changing its underlying data.
By using `torch.as_tensor()` , you can interpret the raw pointer as a PyTorch tensor in a performant manner without risking extra memory allocations or data copies.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1