# Converting a torch.Tensor to a float pointer and vice versa

Tags: python, pytorch, ctypes, python-imageio

I have an image `x` (as a `torch.Tensor`) of shape `(512, 512, 3)` (the first dimension being the color channel count). When I save it as an `*.exr`-file, using `imageio.imsave`, the output is the correct image:

[image]

I need to pass a pointer to `x` to a C++-library. I get the pointer via `p = ctypes.cast(x.data_ptr(), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))`. I also need to convert pointers and I'm doing so by the `as_tensor` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78157395/547231):

```
def as_tensor(pointer, shape, torch_type):
    return torch.frombuffer((pointer._type_ * prod(shape)).from_address(ctypes.addressof(pointer.contents)), dtype = torch_type).view(*shape)
```

Now, when I write `y = as_tensor(p, x.shape, torch.float)` and save this an `*.exr`, I get the previous image repeated in a 3x3 grid (each row being one of the 3 channels, I guess):

[image]

What is going on here? What I would expected is clearly `x = y` (in terms of the data).

Comment: Looks like a  *CHW* - *HWC* mismatch. Please add the image save / load code.

Comment: `y.permute(2, 0, 1)` when you plot it will fix the issue.

Comment: @OriYardenPhD I'm sorry. The actually shape already is `(width, height, channel count)`.

Comment: @CristiFati I'm saving it simply with `imageio.save` without any special parameter. The image is loaded from a data set, but it really simply is a tensor of the aforementioned shaped. So, $x[u][v]$ is the rgb-value at pixel $(u, v)$.

Comment: So which shape is it after all? (512, 512, 3) or (3, 512, 512)? Why is WHC? Doesn't make much sense. How about turning the question into a *MCVE*: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @CristiFati The shape of both, `x` *and* `y`, is (512, 512, 3)`. That's precisely why I don't get the output and assume that something inside the `as_tensor` function must be wrong.

Comment: I can't reproduce. I tried creating a *MCVE* (as question doesn't provide one), before and after the edit (as input conditions changed dramatically), but it works.